# How to make Instagram bot to like comments under post on feed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, instagram, instapy

I want to use the InstaPy package and the following code to like comments under a post on Instagram:

```py
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

insta_username = '***'
insta_password = '***'

session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False)

with smart_run(session):
    session.set_do_like(enabled=True, percentage=100)
    session.interact_by_comments(usernames=["***"],
                                posts_amount=1,
                                comments_per_post=5,
                                reply=True,
                                interact=True,
                                randomize=False,
                                media=None)
```

I already changed and adjusted the code plenty of times, but the one above is the only one that at least logs into my Instagram account, finds the posts and comments but still does not like those comments.

Does anyone see a major mistake or can give me some hint in which part of the code I have to adjust something?

Comment: I just updated on the .10 version of InstaPy, but it still does not work. :(

Comment: Does the bot know, which picture it should like?

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is used to perform likes on your own feeds
#amount=100  specifies how many total likes you want to perform
#randomize=True randomly skips posts to be liked on your feed
#unfollow=True unfollows the author of a post which was considered
#inappropriate interact=True visits the author's profile page of a
#certain post and likes a given number of his pictures, then returns to feed

        session.like_by_feed(amount=100, randomize=True, unfollow=True, interact=True)

Font: https://instapy.org/actions#interact-with-specific-users
```